# replacing a string with a substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm currently stuck on a question where I need to check for every instance of the letter `"a"` in `string1` and replace it with a `substring`.

For example lets say that the `substring` is `"dragon"`, if the original `string1` was `"apple"`, I would need to return `"dragonpple"`.

So far I have my attempts are:

```
def (string1, substring):

     new_string= " "

     for letter in string1:
           if letter ! = "a": 
              new_string.append(letter)
           elif letter = "a":
               a = substring
```

I dont really know how to structure this but this was my general thought process. I'm not sure how to remove the letter `"a"` and replace it with the `substring` without breaking up the string itself.

Also I can't use indexes or the `.remove` method. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: How about doing `string1.replace("a", substring)`?

Answer (score 4):

There's a number of issues here; let's break them down without altering your original code too much:

- You function definition *lacks a name*, define it with a name properly. For example:

  ```
  def replace_a(string_a, substring): ...
  ```

  <sub>I'm guessing this might be a copy-paste omission.</sub>
- `if letter ! = "a":` is a `SyntaxError`, `! =` doesn't get interpreted as `!=` (but as two separate operators `!` and `=`), unfortunately, that needs fixing too.
- `elif letter = "a":` is another `SyntaxError`; *assignment statements* should not be confused with equality checks, that is `=` is not similar to using `==`.
- `new_string.append(letter)` is a `TypeError`; the method `append` isn't defined for strings, strings are *immutable* and appending is a method that mutates the object. `append` is available on `list`s.
- `a = substring` isn't doing much :-(. You assign to `a` and then simply don't use it.
- FInally, you *don't return anything*. Even if your function created the string correctly, you can't get it back because your don't use the `return` statement.

One approach you could consider is to use a list of character strings and mutate that; lists are mutable so mutate to your hearts desire. Then, you `join` the list in the end and return a string out of all the characters inside it:

```
def replace_a(string1, substring):
    new_string= []
    for letter in string1:
        if letter != "a": 
            new_string.append(letter)
        elif letter == "a":
            new_string.append(substring)
     return "".join(new_string)
```

This yields your wanted result.

If you can't use a `list`, mutate it and then `join` you could resort to incrementally building a new string:

```
def replace(string1, substring):

     new_string= ""

     for letter in string1:
           if letter != "a": 
              new_string += letter
           elif letter == "a":
               new_string += substring
     return new_string
```

This again behaves like the previous `list` based function but relies on `+=` which creates new strings by joining the old value in `new_string` with the `letter` or the `substring` based on the condition.

---

Of course, `.replace` on strings would do the trick as the comment by @yper suggests but that beats the point of explaining how your attempt didn't achieve what you were after.

You were close but missing a couple of basic things, I'd advice you take a look at the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Although I have a few remaining questions. I am pretty sure I am not allowed to use the "join" function that you have here as part of my code since I have not learned it yet. Is there a way to have the code so that it ends with "return new_string or string1?"

Comment: Fair enough @Jessica. I've update my answer to include a solution that doesn't involve lists at all. Hope it helped you out :-)

Comment: I know you didn't mean functional in this sense, but saying "A functional approach is to use a list of character strings and mutate..." is making my head twitch.  +1 for the good explanation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yup, maybe not the best choice of words there :-) Promptly fixed it up.